# Firebase messaging for web. Multiple tabs notifications

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Messaging for browser notifications. Problem is when multiple tabs are open. Notification for every tab is shown. Adding `tag` to options didn't help

```
firebase.initializeApp(constants.CONFIG); 
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(({ data }) => { 
  const options = { 
    body: data.body, 
    data: { link: data.link, }, 
    icon: data.icon, 
  };

  const backgroundNotification = self.registration.showNotification(data.title, options);

  return backgroundNotification; 
});
```

I need only one notification to be displayed even when many tabs with same app are open

Comment: Notice that if using **FCM**, you don't need to register the **setBackgroundMessageHandler** listener in the service worker, Firebase JS SDK will automatically create the notifications for you (when the webpage is not focused only).

Answer (score 1):

Comment this line of code

```
  const backgroundNotification = self.registration.showNotification(data.title, options);
```

and use instead

```
                new Notification(notification.title, {
                body : notification.body,
                tag : notification.title,
                icon : notification.icon
            });
```

- Note that - Tag is unique, If you have 2 tabs and you are sending a push
  with name title: title1 and title1, it will show the push only ones.

Example 3.5:
https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: Adding the **tag** to the payload was the key to solve this, thanks!!